# Parsing a YAML file?

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

How can I parse the following YAML file using yaml-cpp?

```
scene:
  - camera:
      film:
        width: 800
        height: 600
        filename: "out.svg"
  - shape:
      name: "muh"
```

I tried:

```
#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

int main() {
    YAML::Node root_node = YAML::LoadFile("Scenes/StanfordBunny.flatland.yaml");
    
    // throws an exception
    int value = root_node["scene"]["camera"]["film"]["width"].as<int>();
}
```

How can I get the value of the `width` attribute?
How can I get the name of the `shape` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "-" in front of camera means it is an array of objects. So my guess would be:

```
root_node["scene"][0]["camera"]["film"]["width"].as<int>();
```